# How to use DANE with Java?

Tags: java, ssl, dns, dane, dnssec

How can I write a [X509TrustManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html) in Java that used [DANE (DNS-based Authentication of Named Entities)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS-based_Authentication_of_Named_Entities)?

Are there any samples or a library? Or has Java build in support for DANE?

Comment: You might want to rephrase... it sounds a lot like your asking for a resource.

Comment: ... and you wouldn't like us when we see you're asking for libraries or off-site resources.

Comment: @jww and Charles I does not understand your comments. It seems my English is to bad. A resource is for me some things like a file. Can be that you means another thing. --- I search for a solution of my problem. I am open for every possible solution. Sample code, a library, a build in solution or some thing else. Currently I have no idea where I should start. The validating of a certificate via DANE seems me a standard operation. Of course it is very new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BouncyCastle cryptographic library](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) provides DANE support. You can find [dane package documentation here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/dane/package-summary.html).

Comment: This sounds great. Do you know a sample for it. A look on the API doc does not give a hint for beginning,.

Comment: Look at this test sources: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pkix/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/cert/test/DANETest.java